WARP (Wireguard) configuration issue on 3X-UI (VLESS - Reality) Proxy VPS server
!!! UPDATE !!!:

it happened so that there was no extra Application needed for Ubuntu,
just the proper settings should be made is Panel (Xray Configuration -
Outbounds | Routing Rules): 1) you create WARP configu by selecting
WARP button changing nothing; 2) go to Routing rules and add New Rule
which will use your WARP Outbound and that's it. Unfortunately we did
not manage to send all traffic to WARP. But geosite works (like
geosite:reddit, geosite:speedtest etc.).
Maybe someone could advise how to fix it. Thank you!

INITIAL PART:
We are trying to set up WARP via WireGuard on a VPS running Ubuntu 22.04 and using the 3X-UI panel with VLESS (Reality). The goal is to route traffic through WARP.
In 3X-UI Proxy panel we have several settings regarding WARP and Wireguard (screenshots enclosed) so we thought we should:

Install Wireguard on the server;
Create Configuration for it using related data in 3X-UI panel;
Run Wiregurad and see what happens there.

We are not that much into network management and Linux OS but before posting spent some time with AI trying to set things up testing different ways.
What we have done:

Created WARP Configuration in 3X-UI:
We created a WARP configuration in 3X-UI and extracted the necessary parameters for WireGuard, such as PrivateKey, Address, PublicKey for peers, and other details.

Installed WireGuard and Created Configuration File:
WireGuard was installed on the server, and a configuration file for interface wg0 was created using the extracted parameters from the WARP configuration.

Resolved resolvconf Issue:
When attempting to start WireGuard, the error resolvconf: command not found appeared. We resolved this by creating a symbolic link: ln -s /usr/bin/resolvectl /usr/local/bin/resolvconf.

Resolved dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service issue:
There was an issue with the missing dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service service. We resolved this with the following commands: systemctl enable systemd-resolved, sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved.

WireGuard Start Attempt:
After these steps, we tried starting WireGuard using wg-quick up wg0. However, the server consistently freezes and becomes unreachable.

Port Configuration:
We opened the necessary ports for WireGuard and WARP: ufw allow 51820/udp && ufw allow 2408/udp.


Finally:
After starting WireGuard, the server freezes, and we cannot connect to it.
After Server was rebooted like several times the Wireguard was not launched.
System specs:

Ubuntu 22.04
3X-UI with VLESS (Reality) from Github
WireGuard installed via apt for Ubuntu

Big Thanks in advance! Here are the Screenshots of 3X-UI to picture that:



Wireguard Conf file (sudo nano /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf):
[Interface]
PrivateKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ListenPort = 51820
Address = 172.16.0.2/32
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = engage.cloudflareclient.com:2408
PersistentKeepalive = 25

WARP 3X-UI Outbound (Xray Configuration):
{
  "tag": "warp",
  "protocol": "wireguard",
  "settings": {
    "mtu": 1420,
    "secretKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "address": [
      "172.16.0.2/32",
      "2606:4700:110:8dcf:795a:6707:7e7c:61d6/128"
    ],
    "workers": 2,
    "domainStrategy": "ForceIP",
    "reserved": [
      108,
      75,
      59
    ],
    "peers": [
      {
        "publicKey": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
        "allowedIPs": [
          "0.0.0.0/0",
          "::/0"
        ],
        "endpoint": "engage.cloudflareclient.com:2408",
        "keepAlive": 0
      }
    ],
    "noKernelTun": false
  }
}

